# Добавить узел в существующий XML, в ОПРЕДЕЛЕННОМ месте

Tags: c#, xml

Допустим есть готовый XML документ, как:

```
<wpt lat="59.546486655250192" lon="30.110270230099559">
   <time>2017-01-21T07:12:09Z</time>
   <name>001</name>
   <sym>Flag, Blue</sym>
   <type>user</type>
   <extensions>
     .........
   </extensions>
  </wpt>
```

Нужно вставить новые узлы "cmt" и "desc" именно как

```
<wpt lat="59.546486655250192" lon="30.110270230099559">
       <time>2017-01-21T07:12:09Z</time>
       <name>001</name>
       <cmt>21-JAN-17 10:12:09</cmt> //это
       <desc>21-JAN-17 10:12:09</desc> //и это
       <sym>Flag, Blue</sym>
       <type>user</type>
       <extensions>
         .........
       </extensions>
      </wpt>
```

Вставить после тега "name" - это вот оооочень принципиально.

Это возможно сделать средствами XML классов из C#? (если да, покажите плиз как) 
Или светит писать прожку для работы со строками в файле, вырезка-вставка...

Заранее Cпасибо за ценные советы! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если документы небольшие или у вас нет особенных требований по производительности, то, наверное, проще всего будет воспользоваться классом [`XmlDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx) для высокоуровневой работы с XML:

```
string xmlString = ...;

var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlString);

var wptTag = doc.GetElementsByTagName("wpt").Item(0);
var nameTag = doc.GetElementsByTagName("name").Item(0);

var cmtTag = doc.CreateElement("cmt");
cmtTag.InnerText = "21-JAN-17 10:12:09";
wptTag.InsertBefore(cmtTag, nameTag);

var descTag = doc.CreateElement("desc");
descTag.InnerText = "21-JAN-17 10:12:09";
wptTag.InsertBefore(descTag, nameTag);

doc.Save("updated_file.xml");
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно))

Comment: Один только вопрос - после сохранения в файл получается "<cmt xmlns="">21-JAN-17 10:12:09</cmt>", как избавиться от xmlns="" ?

Comment: @GregoryGustavin хм, странно, у меня все в порядке. А попробуйте после создания тэга вписать `cmtTag.Attributes.RemoveAll();`?

Comment: @Ev_Hyper `XmlDocument` -- это DOM. DOM = медленно. Linq2Xml -- это всего лишь linq-синтаксис к тому же DOM'у. А для больших файлов лучше использовать SAX (в терминах дотнета это `XmlReader`).

Comment: @andreycha вы правы, не нужно было мне заходить на SO в час ночи :)

Comment: @Ev_Hyper бывает :).

Comment: @andreycha Ваш вариант все правильно работает и не создает  дополнительных xmlns="", если его отдельно запустить :) Ну в моем случае cmtTag.Attributes.RemoveAll(); тоже не помогает. В общем у меня до использования вашего кода еще строк 200 кода есть, и т.к. я работаю с XML 2-3 раз в жизни, то в коде присутствует отвратительный стиль программирования (намешано все и в кучу XmlDocument, XPathNavigator, XmlReader, XmlWriter) и сделано "абы работало", никаких требований производительности нет, скармливаются файлы маленькие. Если пересмотреть рационально, то хватило бы одного XmlDocument.

Comment: @andreycha в общем я это банально скорректировал через string.Replace(" xmlns=\"\"", ""); Писалось то попользоваться раз в год)) Еще раз Спасибо ))

Comment: @GregoryGustavin не очень решение, конечно, но вам виднее :). Если что, запостите [минимальный воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) отдельным вопросом.